# Activate Windows spell-checking for controls in own application

Tags: windows, spell-checking

It looks like Windows supports spell-checking since at least version 8.1.

[image]

Does this feature has to be enabled somehow for text controls in own applications or does it work automatically? If the first, what has to be done to activate the spell-checking using plain Win32-API (or SWT)?

Comment: It looks that it's enabled for native Windows controls.